# How do you classify the text in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am very new to using C# and coding in general. I was watching a video on how to make a rpg game using unity, and there are these colored text that i suppose indicates what its supposed to do. I need help knowing how to activate the colored text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The “coloured text” is semi automatic in visual studio as it recognises functions and keywords etc. as long as you install the unity part of visual studio and assign studio as the editor in a correct manner yours should be too. If it recognises you are opening c# it should be coloured. According to your colour selection preferences

Comment: You need to show a screenshot of theirs and yours, and mention your version; the video maker might be running an extension or custom config that highlights more

Comment: The colour itself doesn't actually do anything in C#, but Visual Studio automatically colours different parts of the code to indicate what type of code it is. For example text within quotes may indicate a string of text, which is then coloured a certain way to make it easier to identify. Understanding the possible different parts of the code requires general knowledge of C# -- if the tutorial you're watching isn't clear on those points you might want to find and follow a beginner-level C# tutorial before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is Unity changing the text color of Text through code, I hope it can help you thank you